# is ZendX_JQuery shutdown in zend 2

Tags: zend-framework, zendx

i downloaded zend 2 dev3 but it is missing ZendX_JQuery, is development team going to shutdown ZendX_JQuery in zend2 ?

Comment: You should ask that kind of thing on that project's forum or mailing list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an post from the component maintainer explaining why they are not continuing it in ZendFramework 2:

http://zend-framework-dev.blogspot.com/2011/03/maintenance-of-zendx-jquery-is.html